# Running a Method in Constructor

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I am a newbie. So, I couldn't find the exact words to explain what I want to do. I will try to explain.

I created a class that extends some base class. In the base class I have some methods using the object specific information to run. I mean that we defined with a constructor.

So, in the class that extends my base class, I created a constructor with super, can I call some base class method in constructor in order to run automatically after object creation.

Like that:

```
class Base {
    String someInfo;

    Base(String someInfo) {
        this.someInfo = someInfo;
    }

    String someMethod() {
        return someInfo;
    }
}

class MClass extends Base {

    MClass(String someInfo) {
        super(someInfo);
        someMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: You can call methods of the super class in your constructor, but they will be executed during not after object creation.

Comment: I tried it. It worked but still, is there a better or more formal way  to do it. Some special method in the class maybe, that runs after object created. Because I might want to run some other methods in some conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is more about theory, not practice.

In practice - you can. But you shouldn't do such things. It's about code smell and possibility for hard-to-find bugs. Look at this sample

```
class Base {
  private final String t;
  private final int length;
  Base(String t) {
    this.t = t;
    length = this.t.length();// here you'll got NullPointerException
  }
}
class Override {
   Override() {
     super(calculate());
   }
   String calculate() {
     return "Override";
   }
}
class OverrideB {
  private final String b = "some string";
  OverrideB() {
  }
  String calculate() {
    return b;
  }
}
```

In current sample when you'll try to create `OverrideB` instance you'll got `NullPointerException` - because `b` isn't instantiated at current moment (you can check it by yourself - it is about order of constructors calls).
But you have to options to avoid this problem:

- private methods (they cannot be overridden, only hidden in sub classes)
- final methods (same case as for private, but they can't be even hidden and they available for all subclasses)

PS according to class names conventions you should name your `mClass` as `MClass`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I sometimes make this mistake about mClass/MClass. I think it sounds better now to call the method where I created the object.

Comment: I thought `super(calculate())` was illegal unless `calculate` was static.

Comment: @immibis at the every moment of constructor execution you already have an instance of class... This instance not initialized well, but you have full access to all it's methods and variables.

Comment: @immibis Hmm... You are right - I don't like 'danger' code, so I didn't try it... But you still able use super-type methods. (and after `super` call you again can use current classes methods).